# Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/libgcc2.c

Tags: c++, gcc

Hi I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    in=fopen("miny.in", "r");
    out=fopen("miny.out", "w");
    int n;
    fscanf(in, "%d", &n);
    long long p=1;
    long long i;
    int x;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        fscanf(in, "%d", &x);
        p*=x;
    }
    int bre=(p/10)%10;
    fprintf(out, "%lld", bre);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it it works fine. The problem comes when I am debugging. When i get to the line 20 at fprintf the debugger stops and says the error in the title. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you need it fixed ? The message from the debugger tells you that it cannot find the source code that are part of the compiler generated startup code or standard library of your platform/compiler. You pretty much never need that unless you are planning on debugging the compiler or standard library. Normally you just need to debug your own code - which you should be able to do just fine if you use the `-g` flag to the compiler when you are compiling your code.

Comment: Ok I understand. I as using "step into" to move with the debugger and it stopped at fprintf. However, if I use "next line" it works. I did use "step into" for a long time and I don't know why it hasn't been working since yesterday.