# when i run my code it gives me no output and when i tried to debug it it gave me the error as described below. Need help in resolving this issue

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, while-loop, gdb

when i run my code it gave me no output , while debugging i found that on the mentioned line in while loop below it gives the error

```
Unable to open 'libgcc2.c': Unable to read file '\home\keith\src\mingw\gcc- 
build\src\gcc-6.3.0\libgcc\libgcc2.c' 
(Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '\home\keith\src\mingw\gcc-build\src\gcc- 
6.3.0\libgcc\libgcc2.c')
```

I am using gdb( launch ) for debugging in vs code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>`

void print_converted_num(char* arr,short int stop);
void convert_to_other_base(long long int decNum,short int trTo);
void convert_to_decimal(long long int n,short int oB,short int tB);
long long int combine_number_string(char* num_st,short int oBase,short int tBase);
void check_base(char* num_string,short int o_base,short int t_base);


int main(void) {
    char ch_num[sizeof(long long int)*8];
    short int o_b,t_b;
    printf("Enter the valid native base : ");
    scanf("%hi",&o_b);
    printf("Enter the valid transfer base : ");
    scanf("%hi",&t_b);
    if(o_b!=t_b) {
        check_base(ch_num,o_b,t_b);
    }else {
        printf("native base and transfer base are same . Please try again :)");
    }
    return 0;
}

void check_base(char* num_string,short int o_base,short int t_base) {
    if((o_base==2 ||o_base==8||o_base==10 ||o_base==16) && (t_base==2|| t_base==8||t_base==10||t_base==16)) {
        printf("Enter the number in selected native base : ");
        scanf("%s",num_string);
        long long int number=combine_number_string(num_string,o_base,t_base);
        convert_to_decimal(number,o_base,t_base);

    }else {
        printf("OOPS! ,invalid native / transfer base. Please try again :)");
    }
}

long long int combine_number_string(char* num_st,short int oBase,short int tBase) {
    long long int num=0;
    int value,l,i=0;
    l=strlen(num_st);
    if(oBase==2) {
        for(int j=l-1;j>=0;j--) {
            if(num_st[j]==48||num_st[j]==49) {
                value=(num_st[j]-'0');
                num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));
                i++;
            }else {
                printf("OOPS! ,Invalid num for native base %d. Please try again :)",oBase);
                break;
            }
        }
    }else if(oBase==8) {
        for(int j=l-1;j>=0;j--) {
            if(num_st[j]>=48 && num_st[j]<=56) {
                value=(num_st[j]-'0');
                num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));
                i++;
            }else {
                printf("OOPS! ,Invalid num for native base %d. Please try again :)",oBase);
                break;
            }
        }
    }else if(oBase==10) {
        for(int j=l-1;j>=0;j--) {
            if(num_st[j]>=48 && num_st[j]<=57) {
                value=(num_st[j]-'0');
                num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));
                i++;
            }else {
                printf("OOPS! ,Invalid num for native base %d. Please try again :)",oBase);
                break;
            }
        }
    }else if(oBase==16) {
        for(int j=l-1;j>=0;j--) {
            if(num_st[j]>=48 && num_st[j]<=56)  {
                value=(num_st[j]-'0');  
                num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));
                i++;
            }else if(num_st[j]>=65 && num_st[j]<=70) {
                value=(num_st[j]-'7');  
                num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));
                i++;
            }else {
                printf("OOPS! ,Invalid number for native base %d. Please try again :)",oBase);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}

void convert_to_decimal(long long int n,short int oB,short int tB) {
    long long int dec=0;
    int digit,i=0;
    while(n>0) {
        digit=n%10;  // on this line it gave me the error 
        dec+=(digit*(pow(10,i)));
        n/=10;
    }
    if(tB==10) {
        printf("%llu",dec);
    }else if(tB==2) {
        convert_to_other_base(n,tB);
    }
}



void convert_to_other_base(long long int decNum,short int trTo) {
    char final_num[sizeof(long long int)*8];
    int d,i=0;
    while(decNum>0) {
        d=decNum % trTo;
        if(d==10||d==11||d==12||d==13||d==14||d==15) {
            final_num[i]=d+'7';
        }else{
            final_num[i]=d+'0';
        }
        decNum/=10;
        i++;
        
    }
    print_converted_num(final_num,i);
}
void print_converted_num(char* arr,short int stop) {
    for(int j=stop-1;j>=0;j--) {
        printf("%c",arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970071 **Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-4.9.2/libgcc/libgcc2.c**. However, there is no formal answer there, just a comment with some explanation.

Comment: @CiaPan yeah i looked at it before but could not find anything which could resolve this error

Comment: But the comment to the linked question says: 'You pretty much _never need that_ unless you are planning on debugging the compiler or _standard library_.' I understand you tried to enter and track the execution of the `pow()` function. It's a function from the standard library. Are you sure you need to debug it? It's not hard to test whether the function returns a correct value (a power of 10) without entering it.

Comment: @CiaPan if we just forget about debugging ,the code is not showing any output on normal running

Comment: @CiaPan now I have tried changing the datatype of number from long long int to int and it is working correctly , so i think that it has some problem on doing modulus of long long int number % 10

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int value,l,i=0;
    l=strlen(num_st);`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` (which is an unsigned value) not an `int`

Comment: OT: regarding: `num+=((value)*(pow(10,i)));`  The prototype for `pow()` is `double pow(double x, double y);`  Your compiler should have warned you about this problem

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: the error message has nothing to do with your code.  Rather, it indicates that the utility `mingw` is not correctly installed